# Rename Folder in remote machine

Tags: windows-7

I need to rename the specified folder in remote machines, as all machines contain the same folder in the same path, and we need to rename this folder.
Ex: `D:\Test` to `D:\Test2`

I need a script to get the remote machines name from txt file, and rename the folder on their D drive. bat file or power shell script.

Answer (score 1):

```
strComputer = "hostname"

strFolderName = "\\"& strComputer &"\C$\Data"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolderName) Then
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderName)
    strNewName = objFolder.Name & ".old"
    objFolder.Name = strNewName
End If
```